# Accessing current_user variable in another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to access Devise's current_user variable inside a new instance of another controller. Here is my definition of GetsInterfaceController

```
class GetsInterfaceController < ApplicationController
  def select_current_signed_in_user
   @signed_in_user_here = current_user
  end
end
```

Then I instantiate a new instance of GetsInterfaceController in ClientsController

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def get_current_user
    @gets_interface_controller = GetsInterfaceController.new
    find_signed_in_user = @gets_interface_controller.select_current_signed_in_user
  end
end
```

But I get null error on the @signed_in_user_here = current_user line in GetsInterfaceController when I try this. Anyway to get to the current_user attribute from inside GetsInterfaceController ?

Comment: You can access `current_user` from `ClientsController` as well.

Comment: you don't have to do any of that stuff--you have access to current_user in all your views / controllers.

Answer (score 1):

`current_user` is not a variable - it is a helper method. Thus it is already available in all your helpers and views.

Additionally you **never** instantiate controllers in Rails. The router does that for you.

The only public methods in your controllers should be the actions which respond to HTTP requests.

If you want to reuse a method in several controllers you should be using inheritance, modules (concerns) or helpers. Never by calling a method on another controller.

---

To call an external service you want to create an API client class:

```
# adapted from https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty
require 'httparty'
class StackExchangeClient
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'api.stackexchange.com'

  def initialize(service, page, user = nil)
    @user = user
    @options = { query: {site: service, page: page} }
  end

  def questions
    self.class.get("/2.2/questions", @options)
  end

  def users
    self.class.get("/2.2/users", @options)
  end
end
```

Or if you need to call an external service and for example create several models with the data a Service Object:

```
class SomeService
  def initialize(user, client: SomeClient)
    @user = user
    @client = client # for mocking
  end

  def call
     response = @client.get('/foo')
     response.each do |d|
        @user.baz << d[:woo]
     end
  end
end

SomeService.new(current_user).call
```

Comment: I understand that. This is a special case. This is not a routed controller. It is more of a class that I use when I am making a call to another resource outside the application to a REST API service.

Comment: Then you want to make it a service object and pass it the the current user - don't make it inherit from ApplicationController. Controllers need to be passed a request and ENV to work. https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services

Comment: Did you try making this class a controller, but just don't have any routes to it?

Comment: And its not really a special case - you're just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by moving my code into a Module in lib directory. Works like a charm